# Getting MongoServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:27017 when connecting Mongodb with NodeJS - how to fix?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

MongoServerSelectionError : connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:27017

> I am trying to connect my MongoDB database with NodeJS but I'm getting this error.

> I have searched this error in stack overflow but I couldn't find proper solution.so looking for solution of this error and want to understand what exactly this error is.

this is images of code and error [image: this is code]
[image: 1st image of errror]
[image: 2nd image of error]

Comment: Please don't paste screenshots, use formatted text. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551

Comment: Yes, Thank You its solved my Error and i got it, i will not paste screenshot next time. @WernfriedDomscheit